# ExtJS custom theme: Generating darker icons for panel.

Tags: extjs, extjs5

In my project there is a requirement to create custom theme. The base color of the components is very light(almost white). The issue is the icons appearing on the header of panels/windows(close, maximize) are almost invisible. What are the sass variables I need to declare so that the images used for these panels and windows are darker(in contrast to white)? And in which scss file do I need to include them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to replace those images, in ExtJS 5 you can find them at:

YourProjectFolder/ext/packages/your-theme/resources/images/tools/

There you will have two files, tools-sprites.png and tool-sprites-dark.png
You can replace them there if you are using the standard theme or you can save the new image in your custom theme folder path.

Notice that for this to work properly with all browsers, you will have to rebuild your theme using sencha command.